# Perform an action within a stored procedure depending on the result of another action within the stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I realise that this *must* be a very basic question, but my google-fu seems to be entirely absent at the moment.

What I want to do is, inside a stored procedure:

- Declare a VarChar(1) variable, myVarChar
- Search a table for the value of a corresponding VarChar(1), based on an incoming @myKey argument to the stored procedure, and assign its value to myVarChar
- Perform one of two different Insert statements depending on the new value of myVarChar

As I say, I'm sure this must be quite straightforward, and I apologise for that, but I'm just not seeing the information I want in my searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @myVarChar varchar(1);

Select @myVarChar=MyCol From MyTable Where MyOtherCol = @myKey;

If @myVarChar = 'A'
Begin
End
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use this general format:

```
IF @variable = 'foo'
    BEGIN
    <do some stuff>...
    END
IF @variable = 'boo'
    BEGIN
    <do some other stuff>...
    END
IF @variable = 'neither foo nor boo'
    BEGIN
    <do whatever you want as a failsafe>
    END
```